# What noun describes "turning a cardinal number into an ordinal number"?

Tags: ordinal-numbers, inflections

If I take a singular noun like 'person' and turn it into its plural 'people', I think I'm doing *pluralisation* (or, if you insist, *pluralization*).

What am I doing if I take a cardinal number like '13' and turn it into an ordinal, like 'thirteenth'?  I liked *ordination*, but that already means some kind of religious thing.

Should I refer to it as *ordinalisation*?  I couldn't find ordinali(s|z)ation in a dictionary, and all the Google hits are from software packages.

Comment: I think that 'conversion' is the noun most used.

Answer (score 1):

Ordinalisation should be fine - it's something of a neologism, but there are past uses, and it's pretty clear as to the definition of the word.

I know that some decry the process of verbification, but as you've pointed out with your example 'pluralization', it's not exactly a new phenomenon (and I'd argue that one of English's greatest strengths is its massive and ever-increasing lexicon.

For what it's worth, my Google search of 'ordinalization' came up with a number of hits, mostly in books focused on statistics. Amusingly, one hit included the term in scare-quotes, as though the author recognized the lack of official definition, but were going to use it anyway.